# Finding a filter in ActionFilterAttribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, actionfilterattribute

I created a custom ActionFilterAttribute which I call like this :

```
 [ScopeActionFilter(acceptedScopes = new string[] { "Files.Upload" })]
  public IActionResult Upload(IFormFile[] files)
   {
   }
```

Now, how do I find the value of `acceptedScopes` in the `OnActionExecuting` method ? And how do I check that acceptedScopes was passed to the ActionFilter ?

```
 public class ScopeActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public string[] acceptedScopes { get; set; }

        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext actionContext)
        { 
       
                ScopesRequiredByWebApiExtension.VerifyUserHasAnyAcceptedScope(actionContext.HttpContext, actionContext.ActionArguments["acceptedScopes"] as string[]);

        }    
    }
```

Comment: Can you please tell me what ScopesRequiredByWebApiExtension is?  Is it a class you have made?

Comment: Yes, it is actually irrelevant to my question. Which is how do I check that acceptedScopes was passed and how to I get its value ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how do I find the value of acceptedScopes in the OnActionExecuting method ?

In your code, we can find that you set the value for `acceptedScopes` property while you applying the `ScopeActionFilter`  to action method, to get the value of `acceptedScopes` in the OnActionExecuting method, you can try:

```
public class ScopeActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public string[] acceptedScopes { get; set; }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext actionContext)
    {
        var args = acceptedScopes;
   
        ScopesRequiredByWebApiExtension.VerifyUserHasAnyAcceptedScope(actionContext.HttpContext, args);

    }
}
```

Test Result

[image]

Comment: I can't believe it was that simple. Must have worked too late last night :p Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
string[] ActionArguments = ((ScopeActionFilter)actionContext.Filters.Where(t => t is ScopeActionFilter).First()).acceptedScopes;
```

will work